# Use one 12V 30A timer for two separate 12V inputs?

Tags: power-supply, led, switches, 12v, led-strip

I'd like to use the following timer, rated **12V 30A**, but for **switching two different 12V inputs** at the same time and not having to buy and program two timers. But the timer only have one channel.

[image]

One input is **12V 14A** and the other is **12V 16A**, coming from a PC power supply. It will be used to power two separate LED strips.

What would be the solution?

Comment: You might be able to use it to control the power supply's on/off control the way a PC motherboard does...  However this could be complicated if the timer wants to be powered by the source and the standby supply output is of insufficient voltage.  Realistically this is the wrong device for your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it really is capable of switching 30A DC, then you can connect both LED strips in parallel to the 'LOAD' connection.

Looks like you want the TM630A-4 which is the 12V version, not the one in your photo which is the 250V AC version.

Looking at the datasheet for the power supply mentioned in the comments, it looks it has two separate outputs, so you won't be able to connect them both together.

The timer could be used to switch a double pole relay which could then switch the separate power supply outputs to the individual LED strips.  Or you could use the timer to power one LED strip and also control a single pole relay which switched the second power supply to the second LED strip.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fayfOU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If they are totally separate supplies which the datasheet suggests, there will be a feedback mechanism on each output that keeps the output voltages constant under varying loads.  If you were to connect them together it will confuse the feedback mechanism so that one of the power supplies could end up trying to supply all the current while the other does very little.  It may cope with this, but could also cause damage.

I have just noticed that the information has this -
[image]

Which may suggest that they can be connected together, but I am not certain and I can't see anything else in the datasheet that backs this thought up.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the photo is from Amazon but I am aiming for the 12V version. Can I also connect both 12V outputs from the power supply (https://www.bequiet.com/fr/powersupply/494) to inputs of the timer? That was my main concern.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. What is the electrical explanation on why the power sources cannot be connected together, despite being from the same supply block?

Comment: Updated my answer.